# Decode Function

Tags: sql, oracle, decode

I have a query that has three prompts; Department, From Date, and To Date. One must select the department ID but has a an option to select the date range. How can I make the date range optional? I was thinking of using the decode function but not sure how to write it so the two date prompts can be left blank.

Comment: Not enough information. You should include example data and maybe expected result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a stored procedure you can do something like this in your select statement:

```
select *
from table
where (field > inDateStart and field < inDateEnd) or 
      (inDateStart is null and inDateEnd is null)
```

or using coalesce

```
select *
from table
where (field => coalesce(inDateStart,field) and 
       field <= coalesce(inDateEnd,field)
```

It really depends on your particular situation.  Some queries lend themselves to the first some to the second.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an unspecified date input comes across as NULL, you can do this little trick:

```
with
 TheTable as
 (select 1 dept, sysdate dt from dual
 union
 select 2 dept, sysdate-63 dt from dual
 union
 select 3 dept, sysdate-95 dt from dual
 )
select * 
from thetable
where coalesce(:DateFrom,dt) <= dt
and  coalesce(:DateTo,dt) >= dt
;
```

Need a bit more info on the nature of your data to consider dept as an input... Does the table store multiple dates per dept?